# Wiped GIS project

Tags: qgis, corrupt

I have encountered an error where I open a QGIS project and it has been wiped clean. No layers present but the bottom dialogue box ensures the project is loaded. [image: QGIS Project Interface]

The file was working fine last night, I saved and closed it in a usual manner. Using only QGIS 3.28.0.

This happened the other day with a different file so I saved a backup, from the file size comparison it seems like the original has been gutted. [image: Files]

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: There's so many potential causes, and not many of them are reproducible. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: Hi Vince, cheers for replying. I am essentially just looking for a way to stop it happening again. But if there is many potential causes I see why that might be hard to do.